# Redmine email configuration using Exchange online

Tags: ruby, office365, exchange-server, redmine

I keep getting this error when trying to send test email in Redmine

```
An error occurred while sending mail (501 5.1.5 Recipient address reserved by RFC 2606 )
```

And here is what my email configuration looks like

```
  email_delivery:

    delivery_method: :smtp
    smtp_settings:
      enable_starttls_auto: true
      address: "smtp.office365.com"
      port: 587
      domain: "somedomain.com"
      authentication: :login
      user_name: "no.reply.address@somedomain.com"
      password: "a very complex password"
```

What is the problem with my email configuration? I have this configuration in another application (odoo python) and it is working.

Answer (score 1):

Your Redmine email settings are good.

However, it appears that you are trying to send Test email to non-existing Test domain.

Office 365 is actually using Microsoft Exchange servers, and thus, all of [RFC 2606](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2606) domain addresses will be blocked.

The only way is change you test user (admin or other) email's domain name from "example.com", "example.net","example.org", "contoso.com", "domain.com" or "yourcompany.com" to some other domain name which aren't a RFC 2606 domain address.

Comment: I didn't know Redmine is using the logged user email for testing.